# Java-like properties file to environment variables

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

I need to convert each property of a `properties` file to a environment variable:

I mean, guess this property file:

```
mongo.port=27017
mongo.host=127.0.0.1
mongo.databaseName = test
```

bo.url-jwt=https://localhost:8089/token

I'd like to create them as environment variables as

```
export MONGO_PORT=27017
export MONGO_HOST=127.0.0.1
export MONGO_DATABASENAME=test
export BO_URL_JWT=https://localhost:8089/token
```

Any tool or script in order to get this?

I'm using ubuntu 18x + zsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a short script that can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp1=$(mktemp)
tmp2=$(mktemp)

cut -d= -f 1 props.txt  | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | tr '.-' '_' > $tmp1
cut -d= -f 2 props.txt > $tmp2

paste -d= $tmp1 $tmp2 > output.props

sed -i 's/ *= */=/' output.props
sed -i 's/^/export /' output.props

rm $tmp1 $tmp2
```

This script works in the following manner. Two temporary files are generated using `mktemp`. The input properties file is split on the '=' character and the two respective fields are sent to these two files.

On the first field (the property name), the `tr` command is applied twice. Once for lowercase-to-uppercase conversion, once for changing the special characters to an underscore. The field values are only written to the temporary file after these changes.

Once the processing is done, the `paste` command is used to the put the fields back together into a single file, output.props. Then, two `sed` commands are used. The first one removes any space characters around the '=' character, which would otherwise be a syntax error for the `export` command. The second `sed` command is used to prefix the string 'export ' to each line. Finally, the two temporary files are cleaned up.

Sample output:

```
$ cat output.props
export MONGO_PORT=27017
export MONGO_HOST=127.0.0.1
export MONGO_DATABASENAME=test
export BO_URL_JWT=https://localhost:8089/token
```

Once the output file is generated, source it to actually set the variables in the environment. One of the two following syntaxes may be used for this:

```
. output.props
source output.props
```

Comment: Could you show on post, how to populate generated `output.props` to env variables then?

Comment: @Jordi I've edited my answer with this information. Do note that I have added one more `sed` command to clean up the spaces from the input as well.